# Passing parameters between asp.net webforms using PreviousPageType

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to pass a few parameters between two web pages 
within the source page I have the following properties

```
    private string _testString { get; set; }
    public string TestString
    {
        get
        {
            return _testString;
        }
    }
```

In previous msdn examples the return type was always set to a UI element (`textbox.text`)
However I am trying to pass the value from a dynamically generated link button which is why I chose to use the private accessor

In the click event of the link button on the source page I have the following:

```
    protected void RenderReportInNewPage(LinkButton lb)
    {
      _testString = lb.CommandArgument.ToString();
      Response.BufferOutput = true;
      Response.Redirect("~/stuff/testviewer.aspx");
   }
```

On the target page I have the source page referenced in the aspx as follows:

```
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/stuff/testviewer.aspx"%>
```

And then in the codebehind of the target page I have the following:

```
Textbox.Text = PreviousPage.TestString;
```

PreviousPage displays the public property TestString but it is always null (as I don't think it is getting set but not sure why)

Is is possible to set a private accessor (_teststring) and have that value reflected within the public property? I'd appreciate any suggestions on what I have done wrong.

-Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error. It was not in the setting of the property but in how I was invoking the target page. In order to pass the properties across I needed to user `Server.Transfer` instead of `Response.Redirect`

```
    protected void RenderReportInNewPage(LinkButton lb)
    {
        _testString = lb.CommandArgument.ToString();
        Response.BufferOutput = true;
        Server.Transfer("~/ReportBuilder/viewer.aspx");
     }
```

-cheers